# How to listen DataInputStream Socket in Android without sending data?

Tags: android, sockets, datainputstream

I wrote a class in which I can send and receive data via socket. In this class, first of all, I connect to socket with a specific port and IP then, I initialize outputstrem and inputstram.

I can easily send and receive data, but I can only receive data when there is a request from my side. Sometimes I have to receive new information without sending data.

How can I receive data (listen to socket) without sending data?

```
public class INetConnection{

    private DataOutputStream       outputStream;
    private DataInputStream inputStream;
    private Callback mCallback;
    private Socket socket;
    private byte[] rec_buffer;

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public void setSocket(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void connectToNetwork() {
        if (socketConnect()) {
            try {
                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(getSocket()
                        .getOutputStream());
                inputStream = new DataInputStream(getSocket().getInputStream());
                Log.i("Log", "Streams Created!");
                receiveData();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean socketConnect() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
            Log.i("Socket", "Connection stablished");
            return true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d("Exception mode", "UnknownHostException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Exception mode", "IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void sendData(final byte[] data) {
        outputStream.write(data, 0, data.length);
    }

    private void receiveData(){
        // Again, probably better to store these objects references in the support class
        if(getSocket() != null && getSocket().isConnected()){
            try {
                Log.i("Log", "Ready to receive!");
                byte[] buffer  = new byte[265536];
                int size = 0;
                while ((size = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    Log.i("Log", "Data's been read fully from server");
                    rec_buffer  = new byte[size];
                    rec_buffer = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0 , size);
                    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++)
                        Log.i("Log", "Data i: " + rec_buffer[i]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Log", "Error occured during receiving data");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just read from the inputstream and dont use the outputstream. Why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is the server you are connecting to via the socket your own server with your own implementation or somebody else's server?

Usually the server would behave in a way that it will send data only upon request (at least REST APIs are behaving that way). However, if that is your own server, you can set it up in a way that once socket is connected, it will start sending data to the client. In that way, the InputStream on your client should be able to receive the data without sending anything.

If the server is not yours to modify and is expecting the client to send a request first, then I guess there's nothing much you can do other than to send data from your client first.

Comment: this server is for us and there is a service which send random data of several electronic devices which are implemented in different areas and I have to modify new data with old ones but I don't know exactly which type of data should be requested so I must just listen not request and listen. Is there any way to listen like chat applications?

Comment: How do chat applications listen?

Comment: How is the service API like? Perhaps you can describe a little, and change the names and stuffs (for confidential issues) then we can roughly understand how it is like.


@greenapps, chat applications are usually connected using websockets or some wrapper library around it like Socket.io. The way they are able to get datawithout sending anything is because the server knows when to send to them. So, it depends on the server implementation. If the server is able to start sending data as soon as it detects a new socket connection, the client will get the data immediately (plus network time)